# SSRS 2005 ReportViewer is 'Shrinking' my Reports

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I've put together several reports which render exactly as I'd like them to in the preview in Visual Studio, but when I view them in a web browser, they render as required initially but are quickly squished into the left half of the browser window by the viewer. The zoom level is set to 100% - setting it to Page Width zooms the report out to fill the page but it doesn't correct the line breaks it has made when the initial 'squish' happens.

Does anyone know how to prevent the viewer from doing this resize?

Also, does the ReportViewer automatically disable the maximize button on its parent browser window? I'm quite new to all this....

Thanks, Dan

Comment: Which browser are you using, Dan? Perhaps unsurprisingly for a Microsoft product, I have found that SSRS browser output is only really viewable in Internet Explorer.

Comment: I've tried it in IE6,7,8, FF3 and Chrome. The same thing happens in all the browsers but is less noticeable in FF and Chrome

Comment: @Mark It fails in Chrome, Firefox also.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After a lot more digging, I've found the solution to SSRS shrinking my reports. 
For reference, you have to do three things

1. Delete the  declaration from my hosting aspx page
2. Set the ReportViewer's AsyncRendering property to false.
3. Set the ReportViewer's Width property to 100%

Apparently there is a bug in SSRS 2005 with its XHTML rendering engine which is now fixed with the engine rebuild in SSRS 2008.

Comment: I still have the same problem. What did you mean by step 1 "Delete the declaration from my hosting aspx page"?

Comment: Possibly the width declaration? It's been a long time since I used SSRS.

Answer (score 7):

The report shrinking problem in CHROME when using SSRS 2005 can be solved by the following solution. It works ALWAYS, even if you have more than one page and if you export your report.

Steps to follow:

1. Open Page Footer
2. Drag a rectangle on it
3. Set rectangle Location as:

   - Left = 0
   - Top = 0
4. Set rectangle size as:

   - Width = "the Width of your report"
   - Height = 0.1

By the above settings, the rectangle will not show.

Comment: Noted, although this was happening in all browsers for the reasons noted above.

Comment: This is PURE GOLD! Oh, and this fixed the issue for me in IE. I no longer use chrome for report server because it does not handle date selector fields properly. I want to vote this up like 1000 times.

Comment: I was having this problem in SSRS 2008 R2 in IE. Using a footer as described here fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

The way we do it in my company is to insert a Page header, drop a line component on it, make it the same width as the report, and of a neutral colour that won't be displayed on run time (printing).

The accepted solution above won't work in all the cases, especially when you set up a subscription to send the report by email to the client.

Comment: I actually tried that prior to finding the solution below and it still continued to shrink the report.

Comment: I was having the same issue as above and the accepted answer did not work.  I added a line spanning the entire width of the report to the header and that worked to push it back out to the full width.

Answer (score 0):

Our fix was to increase the `Height` and `Width` by Javascript:

```
var t1;
function manageWidthReportViewer(behID) {
    t1 = window.setInterval("SetWidthForCrome()", 1);
}
function SetWidthForCrome() {

     var mainReportViewer = document.getElementById('iFrameMainReportViewerContainer'); 
    var reportFrame = mainReportViewer.contentWindow.document.getElementById('ReportFramereportViewer');
    var report = reportFrame.contentWindow.document.getElementById("report");
    if(mainReportViewer.contentDocument.getElementById("reportViewer") != null)
        mainReportViewer.contentDocument.getElementById("reportViewer").childNodes[2].childNodes[1].childNodes[1].style.float = "left";
    if (report!=null && report.contentDocument.getElementById("oReportCell") != null) {
        report.contentDocument.getElementById("oReportCell").style.width="100%";

        window.clearInterval(t1);
    }
}

function SetReportViewerDim() {
    var controlPanelHeight = screen.availHeight - 210;

    var mainReportViewer = document.getElementById('iFrameMainReportViewerContainer'); //set
    mainReportViewer.removeAttribute('height');
    mainReportViewer.style.height = (controlPanelHeight-37) + "px";

    var reportViewer = mainReportViewer.contentWindow.document.getElementById('reportViewer'); //set
    reportViewer.style.height = (controlPanelHeight) + "px";

    var reportFrame = mainReportViewer.contentWindow.document.getElementById('ReportFramereportViewer');

     if (Sys.Browser.name == "Safari") {
    manageWidthReportViewer(reportFrame);
    }

}
```